# 'if' condition doesn't work after second cycle

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have a problem with `if` loop. In the script I need to check if difference between `i` and `i+1` row is equal to `0.6` and if yes, then the program should calculate `grad[i]` value. The problem is that in third circle, even if the condition is fulfilled, calculations `grad[i]` aren't performed.

This is part of my code:

```
data = np.loadtxt(files[p])
N=len(data)
print "N: ", N, "\n"
for i in range(0,N-1):
    print "i: ", i
    j=i+1
    Fi[i]=data[i,1]
    errFi[i]=data[i,2]
    Fj[j]=data[j,1]
    errFj[j]=data[j,2]
    t1=data[i,0]
    t2=data[j,0]
    dt=(t2-t1)
    print "dt:", dt
    print Fj[j]-Fi[i]
    if dt == 0.6:
        print " dt =", dt
        if Fi[i] < Fj[j]:
            r[i]=1
            grad[i]=(Fj[j]-Fi[i]) / dt
        else:
            r[i]=-1
            grad[i]=(Fi[i]-Fj[j]) / dt

        print " grad[",i,"]=",grad[i]
```

and the result in console is:

```
i:  0
dt: 0.6
0.148645
dt = 0.6
grad[ 0 ]= 0.247741666667

i:  1
dt: 0.6
0.061069
dt = 0.6
grad[ 1 ]= 0.101781666667

i:  2
dt: 0.6
-0.009578

i:  3
dt: 0.6
0.078995

i:  4
dt: 0.6
0.069982
```

Comment: Floating point is approximate. Just because it prints as `0.6` doesn't mean it's exactly equal to `0.6`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Try using `round(dt, 1) == 0.6` instead. Like @Barmar said, your `dt` will likely not going to be 0.6 sharp. Also, read about floats including the link posted.

Comment: Thank you very much @Barmar and @atru! With `round()` everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are dealing with floating points, which aren't exact. Try working with

```
data = 100 * np.loadtxt(files[p])
```

And compare `dt` to `60` instead. Your value of `grad` (in this linear computation) should end up ok automatically.

If somehow that doesn't work for you, you can after multiplying with 100 also use `round()` on `dt`

Comment: [Round](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html) allows you to round to any decimal you want. No need for multiplication of input or any other similar tricks, otherwise useful 20 years ago.

Comment: @atru don't you need to import math for round?

Comment: The OP is already using numpy. This round is a part of numpy. Also, anything wrong with importing math? I guess in case you want the least amount of modules possible it would be ok.

Comment: `round` has been a builtin in python for some time, anyway - at least since 2.4.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks hmm... Good to know. I'll leave the answer here for downvoting then.

Comment: @atru numpy... True (doh)! Otherwise, yes, it's just a minimalistic POV

Comment: Why not edit and just add what was said? I used to do it too until I learned better. I'll delete all the comments if you edit your post.

Comment: Removed the "outdated".. :) It is though.. It used to be the way to go in C for me. I used it even in Matlab back when I was a true chicken still half-way in the egg.

Comment: @atru I don't get why you haven't moved your answer from the comments to an answer. You post the answer, and I'll upvote. I'm just glad I learned that round is built in nowadays

Comment: You can do it, I answered something similar recently, I can skip this one ;)

Comment: @atru Haha. But yes, my daily work is in embedded C so multiplication and division in the right order is critical. Matlab? I think Matlab autocompletes to `round()` if you try multiplication of this sort LOL